# QML: in loading images dynamically

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to load different images dynamically based on a button press.

```
Rectangle {
    id: rect
    width: 800
    height: 600
    color: "black"
    x: 300
    y: 10

    MediaPlayer {
        id: mediaplayer
        source: "images/video10.avi"
         autoPlay: true
        onError: videoPage1.sendToPost(mediaplayer.errorString)
     }

    VideoOutput {
        id: videoOutput
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: mediaplayer
        fillMode: VideoOutput.Stretch
     }

    MouseArea {
        id: playArea
        anchors.fill: parent
         onPressed: {
            if(!mediaplayer.hasVideo){
                console.log("No media");
            }
             pressX = mouse.x
            pressY = mouse.y
        }

        onReleased: {
            releaseX = mouse.x
            releaseY = mouse.y
            doSomething();
            roi_flag=0;
        }
    }
}

Component {
    id: highlightComponent;
    Rectangle {
        color: "transparent";
        border.color: "black"
        border.width: 2
        property alias text:t1.text;
        property alias ss: image.source;

        Text {
            id: t1
            text: "click"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            width: 5
        }

        Image {
            id:image
            //  width: 130; height: 100
            //  source: (direction_flag ? "images/top.png" : "images/right.png")
            source : ss
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }


    }

}


function doSomething(){
     console.log(rOI);

         count++;
        var obj = 'highlightItem' + count;
        var dir;
        if(direction_flag == 0){
            if((pressX - releaseX) > 0){
                 dir= "images/left.png";
            }else if((pressX - releaseX) < 0){
                 dir="images/right.png";
            }
        }else{
            if((pressY - releaseY) > 0){
                 dir="images/top.png";
            }else if((pressY - releaseY) < 0){
                 dir="images/down.png";
            }
        }

        highlightComponent.incubateObject (rect, {
                                               "x" : pressX,"y":pressY,width:releaseX - pressX,height: releaseY - pressY,text:count,ss:dir});
 }
```

The method works when changing the text but its not working when changing the image, I am getting the error "QML Image: Protocol "" is unknown".

Any suggestions will be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Hi, your code is not a MCVE, for it is syntactical incorrect. E.g.ou can't have JS-Code at random places and you can't incubate a component from within the component itself. Please extend your code in a way, that I can copy it and run it (and in the best case, get the same error as you)

Comment: What is `incubateObject`?  Is that a new Qt function?  What does it do?

Comment: Why in your `Image` object you set `source` property to `ss` which is defined as `alias` for this property?

Comment: I launched your example, and after some editing, i got it working. When swiping the black rectangle, i get to see the arrows. (Ubuntu 16.04 with Qt 5.7.1)

Comment: @selbie Incubators allow new component instances to be instantiated asynchronously. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#incubateObject-method

Comment: @Vaskaelgato I set the source property to ss, because I need to load different images based on user input,a button press.  I could change the text using the "text" property which is set as alias, but getting some error when trying to do it for image. Can you please share the editing you did for getting the code to work.

Comment: @Som [Here](https://paste.ofcode.org/jCLa7eR8mtMMZJHskAqRkv) is a bit more cleaned up version of your code that works for me.

Comment: @Vaskaelgato thanks, the was with the qtversion. Its working properly in qt 5.8.0, previously I was using qt 5.6.0.